# Is it possible to change the working directory in VSCode for a golang project?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have such a project structure:

```
app
   -configs
      -config.yaml
   -server
      -cmd
         -app
            -main.go
         -internal
            -config
               -config.go
```

Inside `config.go` I want to read the config from `configs/config.yaml`.

But as I understand it, due to the fact that my **working directory** is equal to the path to the main file, I get an error `file not found` when I pass such a path `"configs/config.yaml"`.

I saw that in *intellij idea* (if I'm not mistaken) in a similar situation, they just changed the **working directory** to `some_path/app` and everything worked fine . Is it possible in `VSCode` as well? that is, to change the working directory or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Even if there was, the relative path of the source files is irrelevant after the application is built, so it would only work within your particular vscode setup. The working directory for building a go application is going to be within the module directory, and external config files should be locatable via other means.

Comment: How are you running your Go program?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco while I 'm writing , I just run it(cntrl + f5) .At the end I will add a docker

Answer (score -1):

working directory of intellij idea is "cwd" args in vscode, launch.json like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/server",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}" // like intellij idea of working directory 
        }
    ]
}
```